# SQL percentage of column A over column B

Tags: sql, percentage

Ok, so i have this SQL query with rowcount and count failed, like the example below.

```
|CountFound|CountFailed|
|----------|-----------|
|   6510   |    979    |
```

The question is, how can i make a query that will show me the percentage (%) failed. Like the example below..

```
|CountFound|CountFailed|PercentageFailed|
|----------|-----------|----------------|
|   6510   |    979    |       15.03%   |
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And just an FYI, MySQL and SQL Server are two different products, don't mix them. I would suggest to take a look at [ask].

Comment: `100.00 * CountFound / CountFailed`, either repeating the `COUNT` calculation or using the aliases in a Derived Table

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as this

```
select (CountFailed * 1.0 / NULLIF(CountFound,0)) * 100
From yourtable
```

If either of the column does not have decimal part in it then explicitly convert it to decimal/float value to avoid integer division

Used `NULLIF` to avoid divided by zero error

Comment: If a requirement that you have the percent sign, then you may want to wrap that in `CONCAT( {thenumber} ,'%')`

Comment: @BasvanOoteghem - check now

Comment: Why don't you simply use `(CountFailed * 100.0 / NULLIF(CountFound,0))`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want in a pretty database independent way:

```
select concat(cast(cast(CountFailed * 1.0 / nullif(CountFound, 0) as decimal(5, 2)) as varchar(255)), '%') as PercentageFailed
from t;
```

Of course, I would just do:

```
select CountFailed * 1.0 / nullif(CountFound, 0)
```

I see no reason to format this as a percentage as output from the database.

(The `* 1.0` is simply because some databases do integer division if the operands are both integers; some do not.)

Comment: Which DBMS (besides Oracle) is not doing integer division when both columns are integer?

Comment: @dnoeth . . . Postgres (and hence probably Postgres derivative databases) and SQL Server (and I would guess MS Access and Sybase) do integer division with `/`.  MySQL, BigQuery, and Oracle do not.  As you might guess, I always convert to the type that I want for the division (usually with `* 1.0`) so I don't have to remember such trivia.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think you should cover the case where the denominator = 0 (divide-by-zero error). I also agree about leaving off the percentage symbol formatting. Leave that for the front-end app to format; otherwise, you'd have to complicate the SQL to eliminate formatting when the answer is not a valid number (i.e. divide-by-zero).

Comment: @BlakeB. . . . Excellent suggestion.  `nullif()` is ANSI standard and available in most databases.

Comment: Also, `CAST (expr1 AS VARCHAR(x))` is unsupported in MySQL, but `CAST (expr1 as CHAR(x))` is supported (but again, not necessary to begin with if the front-end handles percentage formatting).

Answer (score 1):

**If SQL Server**

```
Select CountFound
      ,CountFailed
      ,PercentageFailed = Format((CountFailed*1.0)/NULLIF(CountFound,0),'0.00%')
 From  YourTable
```